# finding min/max with pyspark in single pass over data

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I have an RDD with a huge list of numbers (length of lines from file), I want to know how to get the min/max in single pass over the data.

I know that about Min and Max functions but that would require two passes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
>>> from pyspark.statcounter import StatCounter
>>> 
>>> rdd = sc.parallelize([9, -1, 0, 99, 0, -10])
>>> stats = rdd.aggregate(StatCounter(), StatCounter.merge, StatCounter.mergeStats)
>>> stats.minValue, stats.maxValue
(-10.0, 99.0)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a working yet inelegant solution using accumulators. The inelegance lies in that you have to define the zero/initial values before hand so they do not interfere with the data:

```
from pyspark.accumulators import AccumulatorParam
class MinMaxAccumulatorParam(AccumulatorParam): 
    def zero(self, value): 
        return value
    def addInPlace(self, val1, val2): 
        return(min(val1[0],val2[0]), max(val1[1],val2[1]))

minmaxAccu = sc.accumulator([500,-500], MinMaxAccumulatorParam())

def g(x):
    global minmaxAccu
    minmaxAccu += (x,x)

rdd = sc.parallelize([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

rdd.foreach(g)

In [149]: minmaxAccu.value
Out[149]: (1, 5)
```