# Spark RDD: How to calculate statistics most efficiently?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, distributed-computing, rdd, apache-spark-mllib

Assuming the existence of an RDD of tuples similar to the following:

```
(key1, 1)
(key3, 9)
(key2, 3)
(key1, 4)
(key1, 5)
(key3, 2)
(key2, 7)
...
```

What is the most efficient (and, ideally, distributed) way to compute statistics corresponding to each key? (At the moment, I am looking to calculate standard deviation / variance, in particular.) As I understand it, my options amount to:

1. **Use the [`colStats` function in MLLib](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.mllib.html#pyspark.mllib.stat.Statistics.colStats):** This approach has the advantage of easily-adaptable to use other `mllib.stat` functions later, if other statistical computations are deemed necessary. However, it operates on an RDD of `Vector` containing the data for each column, so as I understand it, this approach would require that the full set of values for each key be collected on a single node, which would seem non-ideal for large data sets. Does a Spark `Vector` always imply that the data in the `Vector` be resident locally, on a single node?
2. **Perform a [`groupByKey`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.RDD.groupByKey), then [`stats`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.RDD.stats):** Likely shuffle-heavy, [as a result of the `groupByKey` operation](https://databricks.gitbooks.io/databricks-spark-knowledge-base/content/best_practices/prefer_reducebykey_over_groupbykey.html).
3. **Perform [`aggregateByKey`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.RDD.aggregateByKey), initializing a new [`StatCounter`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/util/StatCounter.html), and using [`StatCounter::merge`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/util/StatCounter.html#merge(org.apache.spark.util.StatCounter)) as the sequence and combiner functions:** This is the approach [recommended by this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37528042), and avoids the `groupByKey` from option 2. However, I haven't been able to find good documentation for `StatCounter` in PySpark.

I like Option 1 because it makes the code more extensible, in that it could easily accommodate more complicated calculations using other MLLib functions with similar contracts, but if the `Vector` inputs inherently require that the data sets be collected locally, then it limits the data sizes on which the code can effectively operate. Between the other two, Option 3 *looks* more efficient because it avoids the `groupByKey`, but I was hoping to confirm that that is the case.

Are there any other options I haven't considered? (I am currently using Python + PySpark, but I'm open to solutions in Java/Scala as well, if there is a language difference.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [finding min/max with pyspark in single pass over data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36559809/finding-min-max-with-pyspark-in-single-pass-over-data)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try `reduceByKey`. It's pretty straightforward if we only want to compute the `min()`:

```
rdd.reduceByKey(lambda x,y: min(x,y)).collect()
#Out[84]: [('key3', 2.0), ('key2', 3.0), ('key1', 1.0)]
```

To calculate the `mean`, you'll first need to create `(value, 1)` tuples which we use to calculate both the `sum` and `count` in the `reduceByKey` operation. Lastly we divide them by each other to arrive at the `mean`:

```
meanRDD = (rdd
           .mapValues(lambda x: (x, 1))
           .reduceByKey(lambda x, y: (x[0]+y[0], x[1]+y[1]))
           .mapValues(lambda x: x[0]/x[1]))

meanRDD.collect()
#Out[85]: [('key3', 5.5), ('key2', 5.0), ('key1', 3.3333333333333335)]
```

For the `variance`, you can use the formula `(sumOfSquares/count) - (sum/count)^2`,
which we translate in the following way:

```
varRDD = (rdd
          .mapValues(lambda x: (1, x, x*x))
          .reduceByKey(lambda x,y: (x[0]+y[0], x[1]+y[1], x[2]+y[2]))
          .mapValues(lambda x: (x[2]/x[0] - (x[1]/x[0])**2)))

varRDD.collect()
#Out[106]: [('key3', 12.25), ('key2', 4.0), ('key1', 2.8888888888888875)]
```

I used values of type `double` instead of `int` in the dummy **data** to accurately illustrate computing the average and variance:

```
rdd = sc.parallelize([("key1", 1.0),
                      ("key3", 9.0),
                      ("key2", 3.0),
                      ("key1", 4.0),
                      ("key1", 5.0),
                      ("key3", 2.0),
                      ("key2", 7.0)])
```