# Spark : Average of values instead of sum in reduceByKey using Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

When reduceByKey is called it sums all values with same key. Is there any way to calculate the average of values for each key ?

```
// I calculate the sum like this and don't know how to calculate the avg
reduceByKey((x,y)=>(x+y)).collect


Array(((Type1,1),4.0), ((Type1,1),9.2), ((Type1,2),8), ((Type1,2),4.5), ((Type1,3),3.5), 
((Type1,3),5.0), ((Type2,1),4.6), ((Type2,1),4), ((Type2,1),10), ((Type2,1),4.3))
```

Comment: I guess that you meant reduceByKey (as in the title). Please show an exemple of the code you tried. ReduceByKey does not have a default aggregation, so if it does the sum, you asked it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spark RDD: How to calculate statistics most efficiently?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39981312/spark-rdd-how-to-calculate-statistics-most-efficiently)

Comment: you need both sum and count separaterly, see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29930110/calculating-the-averages-for-each-key-in-a-pairwise-k-v-rdd-in-spark-with-pyth

Comment: Documentation in scala for aggregateByKey: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions

Comment: I asked and answered a similar question a while back, and it (the following URL) may help you and others: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29930110/calculating-the-averages-for-each-key-in-a-pairwise-k-v-rdd-in-spark-with-pyth

Answer (score 21, accepted):

One way is to use mapValues and reduceByKey which is easier than aggregateByKey.

```
.mapValues(value => (value, 1)) // map entry with a count of 1
.reduceByKey {
  case ((sumL, countL), (sumR, countR)) => 
    (sumL + sumR, countL + countR)
}
.mapValues { 
  case (sum , count) => sum / count 
}
.collect
```

[image: https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/learning-spark/9781449359034/ch04.html]
https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/learning-spark/9781449359034/ch04.html

Answer (score 1):

there's lots of ways...  but a simple way is to just use a class that keeps track of your total and count and computes average at the end.  something like this would work.

```
class AvgCollector(val tot: Double, val cnt: Int = 1) {
  def combine(that: AvgCollector) = new AvgCollector(tot + that.tot, cnt + that.cnt)
  def avg = tot / cnt 
}

val rdd2 = {
  rdd
  .map{ case (k,v) => (k, new AvgCollector(v)) }
  .reduceByKey(_ combine _)
  .map{ case (k,v) => (k, v.avg) }
}
```

... or you could use aggregateByKey with a tweak to the class

```
class AvgCollector(val tot: Double, val cnt: Int = 1) {
  def ++(v: Double) = new AvgCollector(tot + v, cnt + 1)
  def combine(that: AvgCollector) = new AvgCollector(tot + that.tot, cnt + that.cnt)
  def avg = if (cnt > 0) tot / cnt else 0.0
}

rdd2 = {
  rdd
  .aggregateByKey( new AvgCollector(0.0,0) )(_ ++ _, _ combine _ )
  .map{ case (k,v) => (k, v.avg) }
}
```