# Calculating Average of User Ratings and Mapping According to Userid on RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

First of all I just start to learn scala so if the question that I am asking so easy sorry for that.

I have a data of ratings which is val ratings: `RDD[Rating](userid, movieid, rating)`

I want to calculate every user's average and creating a `RDD (userid, average_rating)`.

After that I will filter the ratings data according to the average rating of the user like if a user average rating is 2.0 then O will take only the rows which ratings is greater and equal to their average rating.

Here what I have tried so far:

```
val ratings= DATA.filter(row => row!= first_header).map{ fields =>                              
                                new Rating(
                                        fields.split(",")(0).toInt,
                                        fields.split(",")(1).toInt,
                                        fields.split(",")(2).toDouble)         
                                }

// Calculating User Average
    val counts = ratings.map(item => (item.user,item.rating) )
    val goodratingsum = counts.mapValues(value => (value, 1)) // map entry with a count of 1
                                    .reduceByKey {
                                    case ((sumL, countL), (sumR, countR)) => 
                                    (sumL + sumR, countL + countR)
                            }
                            val goodratings = goodratingsum.mapValues { 
                            case (sum , count) => sum / count 
                            }
                            .collect

 // Trying to create a new RDD which is filtered according to each user average of ratings.

    val goodRatings = ratings.filter(r => r.user == avguserrat._1 && ((r.rating : Double) >= avguserrat._2))
```

Error:
But when I tried to reach the userid and average rating from reduced data avguserrat:

```
-value _1 is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Int, Double)]
-value _2 is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Int, Double)]
```

Why I cannot reach the values of userid and their average ratings.

Comment: `reduceByKey((v1,v2)=> ((v1 + v2)/v1))` is definitely not giving you the average. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40087483/spark-average-of-values-instead-of-sum-in-reducebykey-using-scala

Comment: I'd suggest you to use the dataframe API instead of the RDD API. The dataframe API is much easier and more intuitive to use, and is probably more beginner-friendly.

Comment: @mck i am not allowed to use DF so i have to solve it with RDD. Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: @mck Thank you I hace solve the avarge problem. But cant reach the values.